# docker の mount されたファイルの所有者の解決

Tags: docker

docker は -v によってファイル・ディレクトリをマウントすることができますが、それを行った際のファイルの所有者の解決はどのように行われますか？

というのも、 docker のホスト側でもコンテナ側でもユーザーの設定は行い得ると考えていて、当然、外と中のユーザー設定は違いますが、このとき docker はどうこれを解決するのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. linux のファイルシステム(ext4)では、ファイルシステム上のそれぞれのファイルの情報として、ユーザーID, グループID を保持する。
2. linux は、ファイル情報として記載されているユーザーID, グループID に対して、そのIDがOS上に登録されていなければ、その数字をそのまま所有者・グループとして表示する (e.g. `ls -al`)
3. つまり、 OS とファイルシステムは割と直交している。ので mount して host と container でファイルシステムを共有したからといって、（ユーザー周りで）特に取り立てて行わなければならないことはない。